# Angular ui bootstrap typeahead highlighter design

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hello I found out how to customise search list with css:

```
    .dropdown-menu li.active  a{
    background-color:lightBlue;
    background:lightBlue;
    color: green!important;
}
```

[image]

But I can't get rid of the highlighter that appears in blue by default on mouseover:

[image]

I have tried to inspect from browser but can't find what element is being styled and thats why I can't style this further.

Here are the docs:

[angular ui bootstrap typeahead docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for now:

```
.dropdown-menu > li.active * {
   background-color: lightBlue!important; 
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help people to understand the problem.